# How do I copy an Advanced Custom Field field group in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I use the popular Advanced Custom Field plugin to WordPress.  I've noticed a lot of my pages use the same custom fields.

What is the simplest way to copy an Advanced Custom Field field group in WordPress so that I may repeat and slightly alter one across multiple page templates.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey have you tried with ACF clone plugin? Here is the link of that. 
     https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/clone/

Comment: Thanks for the comment @NarendraSolanki.  Not yet, but I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACF is made, so there shouldn't be a real reason to copy a group -

If you want the same fields on multiple templates/post types/ categories etc. you can implement them in the "Or add rule group" section -

Here you can have a many as you want.

If you then desire, that only one of the categories(or whatever), should have a specific field, then you take that field out of the rule group, and put it into a new one.

Meaning, everthing that is shared could be combined into one group, and everything that is unique should have it's own.

You can even write custom end points, if the conditions for the rule group doesn't match your needs, but that is more advanced.

Good luck to ya!

Comment: I don't agree at all, I'm creating a complex flexible content page with dozens of layouts, requiring me to use clone fields for each layout due to it becoming unstable trying to create it all on one page, I've had to make dozens of complicated field sets as many as 6 times each, not identical so can't clone, and with duplicate I still can't combine sets if their in different field groups, so 100%, a copy function would be extremely helpful in my case and would have saved me many hours of work.

Comment: @GibsonFX - this answer is also from 2018 - A lot of thing with ACF has changed since then

Answer (score 1):

My opinion - it is better not to copy Fields Groups, better to create one that will be used for a few pages.
For example if you want to assign field "Title" to a few pages, then you can create group "General" which has rule "if post-type = page", it means this field will be used for all your pages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex.  I'm creating marketing pages which are vastly different from the pages of the main site.  I'd rather not clutter all the pages of the website with custom fields which will only be used on a few pages.  I'm currently bonding the field groups to "if page-template = [marketing page template]" and each individual marketing page has a different template because each is so different from the other.  If I could add multiple templates per page, that would be great.  But, looks like I can't...

Comment: @Nautic20 You can use, "Or Add Rule Group" to specify other templates..

Comment: @Stender Yes! Not exactly what I was trying to do, but it worked! Please reply to this question with this comment as an answer so I can give you credit for it.  Thanks